# How to provide different behavior to the same ng-include if I have it multiple times on the same view?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, calendar

I want to be able to have different behavior (show 3 different dates based on what day you picked) for the same calendar which I include 3 times in my main html view.

So I have an html view with 3 ng-include blocks of the same calendar, which I have in another file. I need to somehow separate the behavior for each calendar... I have a controller for the calendar and I also have a controller for the main view which I mention down below. My main html code looks like this:

```
<div ng-include="template.calendar"></div>
<h4>{{dateCalendar1}}</h4>
<div ng-include="template.calendar"></div>
<h4>{{dateCalendar2}}</h4>
<div ng-include="template.calendar"></div>
<h4>{{dateCalendar3}}</h4>
```

Here is the code for the calendar.html template:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="CalendarController" style="text-align:left; padding-bottom:10px">
<label>Día: </label>
<div class="row">
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" ng-change="actualizarFecha()" close-text="Close"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "different behaviour". How should they behave differently?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a directive instead of an `ng-include`

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu... done.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need some kind of reusable component where each component have isolated scope. In AngularJS, these are called as [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Create a directive, for your calendar, and reuse it at same page. Ensure that you're using isolated scope for your directive.